# how to create a Calendar with task or activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I've spent more than a week almost a month for searching on how to create a CalendarView with task or activities inside its Cell like this

[image]

but I've only ended up creating a like

[image]

My Future depends on it. huhuhuh Help Me Guys..  :(, I need you guys, give me some links or tutorial on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question wright, you need kind of a this example https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView

Works fine. I am using it in my project!
Good luck!

Comment: Do you have Screen shots like what your app looks like.. ? @Nurlan Nabiyev

Comment: @Dodong Not yet. Was that link helpful? Is that what you need?

Comment: yes it gives me some idea but how could i display the description of the events instead of the dots? please help me.. my mother will disowned me if i cant finish this project.. @Nurlan